# Why Ritchie Blackmore hated "When a Blind Man Cries"?

Tags: history, deep-purple

In wikipedia [it is written](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/When_a_Blind_Man_Cries) that:

> Because guitarist Ritchie Blackmore disliked "When a Blind Man Cries", the band never played the song live during his stay with the band, with the exception of one occasion, on 6 April 1972 in Quebec, Canada, when Blackmore was ill, and Randy California from Spirit stood in for him.

My question would be - has Ritchie Blackmore himself or anyone from the Deep Purple elaborated on the nature of such distaste? In other words, what's the reason why Blackmore hated this song in particular?

Comment: I got a friend who is a hardcore Purple fan, to the point of probably knowing every date the band played Stargazer.  :)  I'll ask him and fill in the answer.